# swiftでDatePickerの設定値を保存・読み出しする方法は？

Tags: swift

最近Swiftを勉強し始めた初心者です。
DatePickerで設定した値をNSDate型で保存したいのですが、

```
@IBAction func changed(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let date2 = datepicker1.date

    let myDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    myDefault.setObject(date2,forKey:"date")
    myDefault.synchronize()

}
```

のような記述で合っていますか？

また、保存した値を読み出したいのですが
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let date2: NSDate = userDefaults.objectForKey("date")
と記述しても
「Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSString' to type 'String'」とエラーが出てしまいます。

どのようにして保存・読み出しすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

NSDateではなくtimeIntervalSince1970に変換してから保存し、[NSDate initEithTimeIntervalSince1970:]で読み込めばいいのではないでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

保存の仕方はそれで合っています。

読み出す方法も合っているのですが、１点だけ、`objectForKey`メソッドは`AnyObject?`型を返すと定義されているので、戻り値を`NSDate`型で受けるならキャスト（型変換）が必要になります。

なので、
`let date2: NSDate = userDefaults.objectForKey("date") as NSDate`

と書く必要があります。
この場合、変数の型は型推論が働くので省略して下のように書けます。

`let date2 = userDefaults.objectForKey("date") as NSDate`

また、NSDate型にキャストしようとして中身がNSDate型と互換性がなかった場合、実行時エラーになるので、キャストに失敗した場合は何もしないようにするには以下のように`if〜let〜as?`と書きます。

```
if let date2 = userDefaults.objectForKey("date") as? NSDate {
    println("date2: \(date2)")
}
```

この場合、もし`"date"`キーに対応する値が`NSDate`型でなかった場合は、実行時エラーにならず`date2`変数には`nil`が入るのでif文の中は処理されません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

let date2 = userDefaults.objectForKey("date") as NSDate

でNSDate型にキャストしてから、

if let date2 = userDefaults.objectForKey("date") as? NSDate {
    println("date2: \(date2)")
}

で、キャスト失敗時の処理をするということでしょうか？
そのようにして再度実行してみたのですが、
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
とエラーがでてしまいました。

let date2 = userDefaults.objectForKey("date") as NSDate
の時点でキャストに失敗して強制終了され、ifの中が読まれないのではないかと思ったのですが、どのように対処すればいいでしょうか？

Comment: ちょっと違います。
私が書いたのは場合によっていずれかの方法を使い分けるということで、順番に書くわけではありません。

`"date"`キーに確実にDate型の値が入っている場合は、オプショナル値のアンラップおよびダウンキャストが必ず成功するので、

`
let date2 = userDefaults.objectForKey("date") as NSDate`
`

のように書けます。

ただし、あなたが実行した時のように、`"date"`キーの値が`nil`の場合は、オプショナル値のアンラップに失敗して、実行時エラーが起きてしまいます。

そのため、もし値が`nil`でなく、型キャストが失敗しないなら、値を取り出して（キャストもして）`date2`という変数に格納する、ということを１度に行っているのが下記の方法です。

`
if let date2 = userDefaults.objectForKey("date") as? NSDate {
    println("date2: \(date2)")
}
`

Comment: 無事に実行に成功しました！丁寧に教えていただき本当にありがとうございました！